# How would you access struct values if they're in a struct array in another struct array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a struct in struct array inside another struct array and need to access values in this struct.

```
typedef struct unit
{
    bool isNot;
    char letter;
} unit;

typedef struct line
{
    unit *clause;
    int lineLength;      
} line;

typedef struct fullData
{
    line **table;
} fullData;
```

I am trying to access a unit struct i have created like so:

```
struct fullData Block;
struct Line lines;
```

and then to access:

```
 Block.table[i][j].letter
```

to get the letter in the unit struct.

This is kinda abridged, but the 2d array is massively populated.

Comment: Seems to me you have to do something like `Block.table[i][j].clause[z].letter` where `z` is the unit index you are trying to access.

Comment: @AndréSantos because its only a 2d array, would it be     Block.table[i].clause[j] ?

Comment: Oh, if table it's a simple array of pointers it would be `Block.table[i]->clause->letter` then. `table[i]` is a `line *` so you dereference it with `->` to get a `line`. Same logic for clause, which is a `unit *` and you have to dereference using the `->`.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head of what i'm trying to. Ill make those changes now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you are trying to store letters in each cell of a table. Make the `line **table` as `line *table`. Then you can use `Block->table[i]->clause[j]->letter` to access letter at `i` and `j`. This makes more sense as a table is an array of lines and a line is an array of letters.